# Where can I purchase anti venoms?

Tags: health, south-america

I'm going to be visiting South America next year, and doing a lot of jungle exploration.  I'm thinking I need anti-venoms for the most lethal insects and reptiles.  I'm in Kentucky now. I'm leaving from Florida on a boat and will probably hit Venezuela first. The main anti-venoms I'd like to procure are for the Brazillian wandering spider, the Fer de Lance (Pit Viper), and the Coral Snake.

Does anyone know where I can purchase such drugs?

Comment: You want to buy them in South America once you get there, or you want to buy them somewhere you haven't mentioned to use before your trip?

Comment: Any way I can get 'em!

Comment: You can get 'em in places from Albania to Zimbabwe. Want to narrow it down a bit? Where are you now? Where are you leaving from?

Comment: I'm in Kentucky now.  I'm leaving from Florida on a boat and will probably hit Venezuela first.  The main anti-venoms I'd like to procure are for the Brazillian wandering spider, the Fer de Lance (Pit Viper), and the Coral Snake.

Comment: That's important info thanks Calvin. You should really edit it into your question though because not everybody sifts through the comments looking for the missing details. You might get some more detailed answers for those places on your route.

Answer (score 5):

From the quick Google search you can buy Antivenom from [Red Cross](http://www.snake-antivenin.com/), or you can look at [Survivalist Boards](http://www.survivalistboards.com/showthread.php?t=5499) thread on the same subject, which lists quite a few others including [Emidicinehealth](http://www.emedicinehealth.com/script/main/srchcont_em.asp?searchwhat=1&src=venom&submitimg.x=-694&submitimg.y=-77).